# move data from local to HDFS - data shift

Tags: csv, hadoop, hive

I have comma separated file in .csv format

```
name,address,zip
Ram,"123,ave st",1234
```

While moving the data to hdfs and creating hive table in comma separated, facing column shift.
What properties in Hive will fix this issue?

```
name - Ram
address - "123
zip - ave st"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
   "SEPARATORCHAR" = ",",
   "QUOTECHAR"     = "\"",
   "ESCAPECHAR"    = "\""
)
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION
'hdfs://path'
```

It works..

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).